# SPAudit-w3wp eating up my memory -sharepoint 2019

Tags: logging, sharepoint

I encountered an issue with sharepoint 2019 , SPAudit-w3wp log has generated every single second that eat up my memory.

what is the root of this issue and how can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What information are the logs giving you?

If it's generating loads of logs you need to figure out what events are firing to cause the excessive logging.

Do you have anything custom using the SPAudit class?

Cheers

Truez